# Passing a list to a bottle template, then using this list in a <script></script>

Tags: javascript, python, templates, bottle

I'm using bottle for a very simple one-page website. In my route for '/', I have something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   data = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
   return template('index.tpl', data=data)
```

Then, in my template `index.tpl`, I want to use this data in a script that is located in `<head></head>`:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function doSomething(some_data) {
          return some_data[0];
       }
    
       function myFunc() {
          var test = doSomething({{data}});
          console.log(test);
       }
    </script>
</head>
```

However, this line: `doSomething({{data}})` causes a syntax error: `',' expected. Declaration or statement expected.`

The only way I can get around it is to add quotations like this: `doSomething('{{data}}')`, but then it becomes completely useless because it's a string now, and I have to convert it back to the format I need.

I have seen many solutions on StackOverflow that use `{{data}}` directly in JS without needing quotations, so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. Is this because of where my script is located?

Comment: I think you could have a destructuring problem here. check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Check out `view-source:` or `print()` on the rendered template you're serving:

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function doSomething(some_data) {
          return some_data[0];
       }
    
       function myFunc() {
          var test = doSomething([[&#039;A&#039;, 1], [&#039;B&#039;, 2], [&#039;C&#039;, 3]]);
          console.log(test);
       }
    </script>
</head>
```

You can see the special character isn't valid JS, and although I get a slightly different error than you (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'`), I think we're on the same page enough to offer an answer.

The [docs](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/changelog.html#release-0-8) say:

> The [`SimpleTemplate`](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/stpl.html#bottle.SimpleTemplate) engine escapes HTML special characters in `{{bad_html}}` expressions automatically. Use the new `{{!good_html}}` syntax to get old behaviour (no escaping).

So let's do it:

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function doSomething(some_data) {
          return some_data[0];
       }
    
       function myFunc() {
          var test = doSomething({{!data}});
          //                       ^ changed
          console.log(test);
       }
    </script>
</head>
```

Now we get a clean result:

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function doSomething(some_data) {
          return some_data[0];
       }
    
       function myFunc() {
          var test = doSomething([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]);
          //                       ^ changed
          console.log(test);
       }
    </script>
</head>
```

For completeness, here's my Bottle 0.12.19 code:

```py
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/')
def index():
   data = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
   print(template('index.tpl', data=data))
   return template('index.tpl', data=data)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```